# Service Broker - Stored Proc retrieving data from multiple Databases

Tags: sql-server-2005, service-broker

We are using SQL Service Broker for calling a Stored Proc.
This service broker is working fine when we call the stored proc which executes from one 
database.
But when it calls another Stored Proc which retrieves data from multiple databases
its throwing error " The server Principle not able to access the "databseB",under the current security context". Both the databases use the same login and user name.
I tried to update the login name as per microsoft website. I tried all sorts for things,
still not succesfull. But this stored Proc when execute normally it executes without 
any problem. But when called from a Service Broker its failing.
Any idea what could be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a permission issue. Adding the user to the db_owner role of the database should solve this problem.

Also set the databases to Trustworthy on.